# Does SharedPreferences copy the passed Set<T> into another type?

Tags: java, android, set, hashset

I am trying to convert as Set to an array. I'd like it to store the insertion order of elements placed in it.

The set i am constructing is passed into a `SharedPreferences` object in the putStringSet method.

My code:

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

set.add(element.getTitle());
set.add(element.getMessage());
set.add(Boolean.toString(element.getSomeBoolOption()));
set.add(Long.toString(something));

// set to SharedPreferences
prefs.putStringSet("key", set);

when converting this to an array, the order is not preserved:

prefs.getStringSet("key").toArray();

// elements in data array are not ordered according to the insertion order !
```

It seems that internally, it copies the passed data into another type of Set...

I tried also the other toArray(T[]) method, with no success.

I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Try iterating using an enhanced for loop manually create the array to see if that will behave as expected. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) says that the iteration should be in the order that the elements were inserted but does not say anything about the the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [JavaDoc for LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) it states that:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order.

The key point here is "iteration order". You should use the

```
set.iterator()
```

to obtain the elements in insertion-order.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) state the following:

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this set. If this set makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.

As LinkedHashSet state the following:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

Then it should work.

Can you provide the values you used in your example?

See code below (and try it):

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        final LinkedHashSet<Object> set = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();
        System.out.print("adding following items: ");
        for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
            set.add(String.valueOf(i));
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        set.add(Boolean.TRUE);
        set.add(12f);
        set.add(60d);
        set.add('a');

        System.out.println();

        final Object [] result = set.toArray();

        for(final Object num : result){
            System.out.println("found value: " + num);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is below:

```
adding following items:  1 2 3 4 5
found value: 1
found value: 2
found value: 3
found value: 4
found value: 5
found value: true
found value: 12.0
found value: 60.0
found value: a
```